# Open a directory of images into separate layers using Adobe extension

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I am developing an Adobe extension, from within the extension I want to load a directory of images into separate layers within a document. I am completely impartial to how this is done - so if there is a better approach, please share it with me. My current *working* method involves using the `open()` method which opens a file in a new document, then duplicate the layer of the new document into the original document. An example of this can be seen below.

```
// open new document
var originalDoc = app.activeDocument;
var doc = open( new File( filePath ) );

// duplicate to original document
var layer = doc.activeLayer;
var newLayer = layer.duplicate(originalDoc, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);

// close new document
doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

This method is extraordinarily slow, especially for large images. After doing some Googling I discovered that Photoshop has a [built-in method for creating an image stack](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/image-stacks.html#creating_an_image_stack). This feature uses a .jsx script itself and it can be [found on GitHub](https://github.com/LeZuse/photoshop-scripts/blob/master/default/Load%20Files%20into%20Stack.jsx). Looking around online I found a few people trying to [load a folders contents as layers](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Photoshop/Load-files-into-Stack-automated-action/td-p/10476232), perfect. The main code I was interested in is below.

```
var folder = new Folder('~/Desktop/MyFolder');
function runLoadStack(folderPath) {
    var loadLayersFromScript = true;
    // @include 'Load Files into Stack.jsx'
    var fList = folder.getFiles('*.png')
    var aFlag = true;
    loadLayers.intoStack(fList, aFlag);
}
runLoadStack(folder)
```

I immediately noticed the `@include` method of importing the stack methods, I can not find any official documentation for this (also not friendly with minification). Also, if the script is not placed with the same directory as `Load Files into Stack.jsx` it will throw the error `Unable to open file: anonymous`. And even after solving all of these issues when I run the .jsx script from within my extension using `$.evalFile()` I am having the same error as if the script is not in the correct directory: `Unable to open file: anonymous`. [Error is being thrown on line 762 of an imported jsx](https://github.com/LeZuse/photoshop-scripts/blob/master/default/Stack%20Scripts%20Only/CreateImageStack.jsx#L762).

Any help resolving the error I am experiencing or simply on how to load an array of image paths into layers (faster method) will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I am using within my extension:

```
var loadLayersFromScript = true;
var strPresets = localize("$$$/ApplicationPresetsFolder/Presets=Presets");
var strScripts = localize("$$$/PSBI/Automate/ImageProcessor/Photoshop/Scripts=Scripts");

var jsxFilePath = app.path + "/" + strPresets + "/" + strScripts + "/Load Files into Stack.jsx";

$.evalFile( new File( jsxFilePath ) );
loadLayers.intoStack( new Folder("/c/Users/Me/teststack").getFiles(), true );
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you're trying to run the script from CEP extension, it doesn't have any `@include`'s anymore and you're including the `.jsx` files using the `$.evalFile()` providing a full path to jsx files?

Comment: Yes that is correct on both questions. I have even tried including the files which are `eval`'d within `Load Files into Stack.jsx` into one big file, same result.

Answer (score -1):

Photoshop's inbuilt scripts has a script to do this here's the github link

https://github.com/ES-Collection/Photoshop-Scripts/blob/master/Import%20Folder%20As%20Layers.jsx

use this script inside your CEP extension

Comment: This uses the `open()` method which is very slow and not the solution I am looking for, as I very clearly mentioned in my question.

Comment: I guess in order to do that you will have use the c++ sdk